# IBM create automatically children work items

Tags: workflow, rtc, workitem

I work in IBM RTC (Rational Team Concert); the Project Area I own is built on the IBM Formal Project Management Process Template.

I’m looking for a mean to get work items created programmatically;
I do want when I create a Change Request work item, to allow the selection of different teams and from this attribute(s), create automatically children work items Task directly assigned to the right team/member.

How would you recommend to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a direct answer to your issue, but I guess it would help. It's more like a workaround more than a solution to your requirement.
The work around is divided into two steps:

1. [Create a work item template](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSR27Q_5.0.0/com.ibm.team.workitem.doc/topics/t_creating_work_items_from_template.html) from a CR with all its sub tasks included in the work item template.
2. Create a CR using the previously created template programmatically.

Note: This means that you'll need to create a work item template for each team.